# Is it a bad practice to have methods concerning subclasses in a parent class?

Tags: java, oop

I'll start off right with an example to better illustrate what I'm talking about.

Say I have the following classes set up:

```
public class Vegetable {

    public String color;

    public int weight;

    public boolean isRedTomato() { // <- this is what concerns me
        return this instanceof Tomato && color.equals("red");
    }

    public boolean isBigCucumber() { // <- this is what concerns me
        return this instanceof Cucumber && weight >= 100;
    }

}

public class Tomato extends Vegetable {

    // some tomato specific methods and fields here

}

public class Cucumber extends Vegetable {

    // some cucumber specific methods and fields here

}
```

What I like about this is the fact that I can do something like that:

```
public static void example(Vegetable[] box) {
    for (Vegetable vegetable : box) {
        if (vegetable.isBigCucumber()) { // <- I find this very handy
            System.out.println("Found a big cucumber!");
        }

        if (vegetable.isRedTomato()) { // <- I find this very handy
            System.out.println("Found a red tomato!");
        }
    }
}
```

One may agree that

```
vegetable.isRedTomato()
```

looks more natural than something like

```
Tomato.isRedTomato(vegetable)
```

So my question is, how bad that practice would be? What are some other alternatives?

Comment: Well, you should rather use some kind of **utility class** if you want a handy solution. So yes, in my opinion you shouldn't clutter `Vegetable` with stuff from subclasses. `Vegetable` shouldn't bother about that stuff.

Comment: @Zabuza That's what I thought. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it's bad - you're introducing a bad coupling. But more importantly, a method like `isRedTomato()` is the more fundamental problem. The point of polymorphism is that you ask objects to do things without knowing the details of their implementation - what you're doing is specifically interrogating the details of the object so you can (presumably) do something. That's pretty much the opposite of the goals of OOP.

Comment: @pvg I felt my solution was weak, but couldn't come up with something else.

Comment: Hard to really comment on it since it's not obvious why you want to know if something is a red tomato. It looks like one of those contrived modeling examples you see in tutorials or homework exercises. Those are tricky mostly because they don't actually _do_ anything making them hard to discuss sanely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a better approach is to let inheritance and polymorphism do some of the work for you.  Consider the following:

```
public class Tomato extends Vegetable {

    public void announce() {
        if (color.equals("red")) {
           System.out.println("Found a red tomato!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Found a tomato.");
        }
    }
}

public class Cucumber extends Vegetable {

    public void announce() {
        if (weight >= 100) {
           System.out.println("Found a big cucumber!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Found a cucumber.");
        }
    }
}
```

Now you don't have to do any type checking in your parent class.

```
for (Vegetable vegetable : box) {
    vegetable.announce();
}
```